# How to install wear os app in wear os watch in development mode

Tags: android, wear-os

I have a companion app through which I sync data from phone to Wear OS watch. I have installed the watch apk using USB but when I need to share the apk with my client then how can I share it in such a manner that the Wear OS watch apk will install easily. My companion app and watch apk package names are the same.
My watch is a Samsung Watch 4.
Please help me, I am working on a watch app for the first time and got stuck.

I have uploaded an apk on Play console and when it became live then I have tried to install it on watch via Play Store on my phone, but the option is not available to download it to the watch. I have followed distribution doc i.e. https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-wear.
Basically, I want to share build with the client and he can easily install the apk on his watch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing the watch app from Play Store on the watch itself? Does it show up there?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as there is is no way to bundle watch app with comapanion app we have to pusblish it on play console and it will be available in watch either you can use play store of watch or you can download app from your phone which is connected to your watch.
Thank you.